# Google Sheets OAuth2Request - Bad Request in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

Because Google Sheets Api doesn't support Xamarin, I'm trying to build request by using `Xamarin.Auth.OAuth2Request`.

Following code represents how request looks like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> value = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "range", "Arkusz1!A1:B1" },{ "values", "[Test,123]" }};

var request = new OAuth2Request("POST", new Uri("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/13FC0GZPbFbbOk8MW3N4fRvYq3lNKNZqsQdRsi0uVmgQ/values/Arkusz1!A1:B1:append?valueInputOption=RAW"), value, GoogleAccount);
var response = request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
```

`GoogleAccount` is Account object which was created during logging in.

Unfortunately, I get response: "**Bad Request**": [Screenshot from debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaFJW.png)

I think problem is in third parameter of OAuth2Request (IDictionary parameters), but I don't know how to check it. 
How can I get more information what causing that response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried every method to pass parameters in OAuth2Request but it still doesn't want to cooperate. **Finally to handle my request I have used HttpClient and HttpContent**.

Following code represents my final **working** algorithm:

```
//Initialize HttpClient instance
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

//Dictionary whose contents correlates to body of request
Dictionary<string, List<string[]>> values = new Dictionary<string, List<string[]>>();
values.Add("values",new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "Test", "123" } });

//Serialize Dictionary to JSON
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);

//Create StringContent which is based on JSON
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

//Add authentication header. It can be taken from Account object
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",GoogleAccount.Properties["access_token"]);

//Call Post Request with our new content. Run it asynchronously or not.
var output = client.PostAsync(new Uri(@"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/13FC0GZPbFbbOk8MW3N4fRvYq3lNKNZqsQdRsi0uVmgQ/values/Arkusz1!A1:B1:append?valueInputOption=RAW"), content).Result;
```